# Decay of the coefficients in the Baker-Campbell-Hausdorff formula

Tags: group-theory, differential-geometry, lie-groups, lie-algebras

The Baker-Campbell-Hausdorff formula is a way of expressing $\log(e^Xe^Y)$ in terms of commutators. What I would be interested in is a bound on the coefficients that occur in this formula. For example, from [the explicit formula on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baker%E2%80%93Campbell%E2%80%93Hausdorff_formula) the maximal coefficient of the first order terms is 1, of the second order terms is $1/2$, of the third order terms $1/12$, fourth order $1/24$, and fifth order $1/120$. Judging from this, the coefficients seem to decay factorially. Is there a way to prove such orders of decay?

I am aware of [the explicit formula by Dynkin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baker%E2%80%93Campbell%E2%80%93Hausdorff_formula#Dynkin%27s_formula), but I find it very cumbersome and hoped that maybe something regarding the order of the decay is already known.